# Como enviar o valor de um combo box para o banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Meu `ComboBox` traz o `ID Primário` da tabela `Produto` para ser cadastrado em uma nova tabela que é a `Pacotes`.

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que se eu selecionar outro registro no `ComboBox` ele salva como se fosse o primeiro registro da tabela `Produtos`.

Ai eu precisava de uma ajuda de como fazer pra enviar o `ID_Produto` do segundo registro.

Vou colocar o código do botão salvar que faz a função de enviar os dados pro banco (lembrando que estou utilizando Mysql), lembrando que o `cbxPeca` no código é o meu `ComboBox`:

[image: mostrando como é a tela e os registros]

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Selecionarproduto();
        conectar.Open();

        int DataEntrada = Convert.ToInt32(txtEntrada.Text);
        int DataSaida = Convert.ToInt32(txtSaida.Text);

        //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

        MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
        Inserir.Connection = conectar;
        Inserir.CommandText = Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pacote (ID_Produto, Nome, Quantidade, Data_entrada, Data_saida ) VALUES ("
                                +cbxPeca.SelectedValue.ToString() + ", '" + txtNome.Text + "', '"
                                + txtQuantidade.Text + "', '" + DataEntrada + "', '"
                                + DataSaida +"'); ";

        Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conectar.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Realizado!", "Concluido",
          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        selecionarCategoria();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Falha na conexao!", "falha",
          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Povoando o combo box

```
private void Selecionarproduto(){

        DataTable dtTabelas = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;");

        MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select ID_Produto, nome from Produto", conectar);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        cbxPeca.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        conectar.Close();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtTabelas);

        //cbxPeca.DropDown;

        //carrega as informacoes no combo
        cbxPeca.DataSource = dtTabelas;
        cbxPeca.DisplayMember = "nome";
        cbxPeca.ValueMember = "ID_Produto";
    }
```

Comment: O que acontece quando seleciona outro item da `ComboBox`? A linha das grelhas muda? Não percebi bem a sua questão...

Comment: se eu selecionar outro item e salvar, ele marca como se fosse o primeiro

Comment: Desculpe @Pietro, mas continuo sem perceber... qual item? Em que controlo? Ele "marca" o quê e como?

Comment: No cadastrar pacotes, ele tem um combo box que puxa os dados mostrados no dada Grid inferior, eu quero salvar o "ID_Produto" de determinado registro em outra tabela no banco, porém mesmo eu selecionando outro item no Combo box ele só salva o primeiro registro, pode ver que no Grid superior os dois Registros estão como 1 no "ID_Produto" mesmo no registro "teste2" eu tendo selecionado o outro item no combo box, ficou melhor @JoãoMartins

Comment: Se quiser @JoãoMartins eu posso te enviar o projeto pra você dar uma olhada

Comment: Não é necessário, já percebi o seu problema! A propriedade `cbxPeca.SelectedValue` não está a trazer o valor correto. Edite a sua questão e coloque o código onde está a preencher a `ComboBox`, que de certeza será aí que está o problema.

Comment: Editei @JoãoMartins, Coloquei o código que estou usando para preencher o `Combo Box`

Comment: As propriedades `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember` e `DataSource` do ComboBox estão ali para mostrar suas configurações ou realmente fazem parte do código?

Comment: elas fazem parte, são elas que carregam o `Combo Box`

Comment: O problema é que está a atribuir novamente o `DataSource` quando clica no botão de gravar, então ele volta a preencher a `ComboBox` e a posicionar-se na 1ª posição! Remova a linha `Selecionarproduto();` logo no início do evento `btnSalvar_Click` e terá o problema resolvido.

Comment: OK, vou testar, Obrigado @JoãoMartins

Comment: Valeu galera, funcionou!

Comment: @JoãoMartins, tenho uma pergunta, e se eu quisesse pegar o `nome` do `Produto` ao invés do `ID_Produto`

Comment: Aí acho que bastaria pegar o valor do texto na `ComboBox`: `cbxPeca.Text`

Comment: Obrigado @JoãoMartins